# I want to access the auth()->user()-> in routs like web.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How can I access the user role from auth in web.php please can anyone provide the method to access the user in web.php?

Trying this code

```
dd(Auth::check(),auth()->user());
```

I am logged in and also have authenticated user but showing this output

[image]

Comment: You can't access the current user in `web.php` you can only access it after the `auth` middleware has ran which happens after `web.php` is used to initialize the routes so do it in middleware or in a route handler. You also **should not** try to access the user before the framework is properly booted

Comment: Not a laravel expert but if `Auth::check()` is `false`, how can it return a user instance anyway?

Comment: What is the output of `dd(Auth::user()->email);`…??

Comment: @TalhaF. email of current user

Comment: Then you can access the user role also. Are you using any package?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Auth facade, but as pointed out in the comments it needs to be inside middleware or a route handler, otherwise it won't be properly initialised yet.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Auth::user(); //here Auth functions fail

Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::guest()) {   //but here it will work
        return redirect('/login');
    } else {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
});
```